# Looking to pull values of the most recent version of a row in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server

looking to get some help running a .sql query in Microsoft SQL Server Management...

hoping to filter out older results from a table similar to the following:

| Marker | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | A |
| 1 | 002 | B |
| 2 | 001 | X |
| 2 | 002 | Y |
| 2 | 003 | Z |
| 3 | 001 | D |
| 3 | 001 | E |
| 3 | 001 | F |

I need to filter out older versions of Marker, to keep all values for the unique marker's most recent version such that:

| Marker | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 002 | B |
| 2 | 003 | Z |
| 3 | 001 | D |
| 3 | 001 | E |
| 3 | 001 | F |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Seems like you want [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group), but replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
--Create an extra column to identify the most recent Version for each Marker.
WITH prelim AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Marker ORDER BY [Version] DESC) as row_num
    FROM tablename
)
SELECT *
FROM prelim
WHERE row_num = 1  --Filters out older results
```